# Problem with ManyToMany and JPA EclipseLink

Tags: java, orm, jpa, eclipselink

I've got a ManyToMany Relationship with composite key between a User and a Group in JPA EclipseLink. My Implementation looks like that:

User Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="mbm_user")
public class User extends CanAccessBook{

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(nullable = false)
private Long id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="user",cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
private List<GroupMembership> groups = new ArrayList<GroupMembership>();

  /**
   GETTER & SETTER
  **/
}
```

Group Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="mbm_group")
public class Group extends CanAccessBook{

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(nullable = false)
private Long id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="group", cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
private List<GroupMembership> users = new ArrayList<GroupMembership>();

  /**
   GETTER & SETTER
  **/
}
```

GroupMembership Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "group_user")
@IdClass(UserGroupPK.class)
public class GroupMembership {

@Id
@ManyToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="USERID")
private User user;

@Id
@ManyToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="GROUPID")
private Group group;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date joinedAt = new Date();

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date validUntil;

  /**
   GETTER & SETTER
  **/
}
```

UserBookPK Class:

```
public class UserBookPK{

@Id
@Column(name="BOOKID")
private Long book;

@Id
@Column(name="USERID")
private Long user;

public Long getBook() {
    return book;
}

public void setBook(Long book) {
    this.book = book;
}

public Long getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(Long user) {
    this.user = user;
}
}
```

My JUnit Tests are report no errors, but if I test it on my Tomcat, I'm getting the following errors

> Exception [EclipseLink-59] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.1.v20100817-r8050): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
>   Exception Description: The instance variable [groupId] is not defined in the domain class [de.kapieren.mbm.server.model.GroupMembership], or it is not accessible.
>   Internal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: groupId
>   Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping[groupId-->group_user.GROUPID]
>   Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(de.kapieren.mbm.server.model.GroupMembership --> [DatabaseTable(group_user)])
>
> Exception [EclipseLink-59] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.1.v20100817-r8050): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
>   Exception Description: The instance variable [userId] is not defined in the domain class [de.kapieren.mbm.server.model.GroupMembership], or it is not accessible.
>   Internal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: userId
>   Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping[userId-->group_user.USERID]
>   Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(de.kapieren.mbm.server.model.GroupMembership --> [DatabaseTable(group_user)])
>
> Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.1.v20100817-r8050): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
>   Exception Description: An internal error occurred accessing the primary key object [202].
>   Internal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: groupId
>   Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(de.kapieren.mbm.server.model.GroupMembership --> [DatabaseTable(group_user)])

Whats going wrong here?

Comment: Starting hint:  What happens when you change User user --> User userId...

Comment: For completeness sake, can you post your Group class as well.

Comment: the Group class is still there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the exactly same code with a windows machine and it works without problems.
I think the problem is the JVM of MAC OS (I'm working with Mac OS). So I have to continue my work on a windows VM. this issue seems to be documented by [EclipseLink](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink_Exception_Error_Reference_%28ELUG%29#Descriptor_Exceptions_.281_.E2.80.93_202.29) (Exception 59).
This is very bad for me and I think this will be my Last time I gave Java a try....

Answer (score 1):

You should be using @JoinColumn instead of @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn for the @ManyToOnes.

Comment: Doesn't help, still the same problem :( Curious thing is that my JUnit tests are okay, but with Tomcat these Exception are thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `UserBookPK` class, but it's not referenced anywhere else. I assume this is supposed to be `UserGroupPK`? In which case it is wrong. The fields should be instances of `User` and `Group`, for one. It should be Serializable (but not include a version id, for some reason).

Better yet, don't use `@IdClass` at all. It's only there for backwards compatibility. Put a surrogate key on `GroupMemberShip` and use that to link everything together. Or if you really want the composite primary key, go for an `@EmbeddedId`. Since this is just the relationship modelled as object, that does make some sense.

You don't necessarily need to map the intermediate class either, there is an `@ManyToMany` that sometimes works.